# Delete files using pentaho

Tags: pentaho, kettle, data-integration

I want to know how to delete files based the creation date using a kettle job. I have a log folder which contains log files for last one year. But I want to keep only last week log files. The job should be deleting all the log files which are more than one week old.
There is a delete file option in pentaho job. But how do we get file creation date and delete the files accordingly

Comment: what's the step name you use to delete files?

Answer (score 3):

You can do that in a transformation.
Below shown is the steps required.
[image]

1. Here you can get the filenames by providing the directory name in `Get File Names` step. (It gives additional info such as `lastmodifieddate` of file as a column) 

 2. Then you can write some java code to filter the filenames. eg: (today-7days)  and send more than one week old filenames to next step.

 3. Use `Process Files` to delete files. Select Operation as delete and Source filename field as `filename`. 
Finally you can call the transformation from a job in order to schedule it.

**P.S** If you don't like the `java filter` step You can also get today's date from `Get System info` step and you can reduce seven days from todays date in `Calculator` step then `filter rows` step can be used accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. I will try the steps you mentioned here.

Comment: Example for Java Filter - Condtion Java Expression: "`filename.contains("123")`"